# codeigniter session duplicate with cloudflare

Tags: codeigniter, session, cloudflare, ion-auth

I'm using Ion Auth social

https://github.com/ghosthouse/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth-Social

and throughout my web check if the user has a session started or not.

`if ($ this-> ion_auth-> logged_in ()) {
}`

For this reason in /application/config/autoload.php charge

`$ autoload ['libraries'] = array ('ion_auth');`

in my localhost everything is perfect, but in my website protected with cloudflare, create multiple sessions just with this:

`__ci_last_regenerate | i: 1544893031;`

creates more than 50 sessions per second with just this info which overloads my sql, obviously it is a problem of codeigniter sessions with cloudflare, I have already created the request in the codeigniter github but it does not seem to matter to them.

So I'm wondering if you can share an option / solution, so that only one codeigniter session is created when the user logs in Ion Auth.

Thank you.

Comment: This is mostly a server issue related to health checks that keep reloading session and there are a lot of questions like this but sadly no answer or its unclear. My suggestion is to load it manually in your controller and remove it from autoload

Comment: but as in the whole site I have to check if the user is login or not, then I would have to load the session library in each controller? thanks for your answer.

Comment: Nope, you don't have to do so, just load it once in `MY_Controller` if you have one and if you don't, you should.

Comment: How am I a newbie in codeigniter 3.x I would appreciate it if you share a small example in code? thanks for your help friend do not know how much and been looking for a solution to this.